# Problems with jQuery onchange on ios

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari, mobile-safari

I'm having problems with the jQuery `onchange` event not working in Safari on my iPhone.

This is where the `onchange` is:

```
//Detects change in location and updates with location name and address
$('#location').on('change', function () {
    var serviceId = $("#location").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: 'utilities/fetchdata?fetch=locationbyid&location=' + serviceId + '',
        success: function (data) {
            var locationData = JSON.parse(data);
            document.getElementById("location-name").innerHTML = locationData.name;
            document.getElementById("location-address1").innerHTML = locationData.address;

            //Fetch servies offered by that location
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: 'utilities/fetchdata?fetch=services&location=' + serviceId + '',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    var newOptions = JSON.parse(data);

                    var $el = $("#service");
                    $el.empty(); // remove old options
                    $.each(newOptions, function(key,value) {
                        $el.append($("<option></option>")
                            .attr("value", value).text(key));
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This is what it is listening on:

```
                <select name="location" class="form-control" id="location">
                <option disabled selected>-- Velg Lokasjon --</option>
                <?php
                //Fetch locations
                if (! $locations = $locationData->fetchHTMLINPUT()) {
                    echo $locations;
                } else {
                    echo "<option disabled>Systemfeil oppsto</option>";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
```

What I need it to do is fire the event consistently as this is where it fetches the next step for the user to follow.

Expected behaviour:

- Fetch the next input fields for use in the select

What I think is weird is that it works in Chrome on my desktop as well as Edge.

Could anyone point me to a workaround for use on mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

I kinda figured it out. Seems like mobile iOS browsers can't refresh the contents of a select after the HTML has been rendered, but changing the HTML using f.ex `$('#service').html(data);` works like a charm, though the HTML has to be generated server side.